# ImageList: 32-bit Images lose quality

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, imagelist

I'm using `ImageList` for `TreeView` and `ListView`. I've first set the image quality to 32 bit and then added images which are semi-transparent. The quality looks OK, but after a couple of minutes coding, compiling and executing the application, the quality looks bad.

See screenshot: 
  [image]

Used properties

```
ColorDepth: Depth32Bit
ImageSize: 16; 16
TransparentColor: Transparent
```

There are black pixels behind pixels which were semi-transparent but not fully transparent.

Re-adding all images restores the original quality, but after a couple of minutes, it looks like on the right side of the screenshot.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? I bet it works fine if you load up the image list at runtime. Probably a bug in the VS code that stores/loads the image list state at designtime.

Comment: It's VS2010 Ultimate. I also first thought about loading them at runtime, but that is not the way it *should* be. Any other ideas?

Comment: Loading at runtime from a resource is exactly what I would do. Then I can choose a size that matches the font scaling.

Comment: @bytecode77 Cannot respond in proper thread, because Hans Passant removed his answer. Regarding adding images to imagelist - this is quite weird, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902091/32-bit-images-on-imagelist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like alpha channel data is lost when images are stored as `ImageStream` (default behavior of VS Designer).
So if you are ok to stop using Designer to set images in `ImageList`, you can use semitransparent images up to `ColorDepth.Depth32Bit`.
It is very inconvenient but it works.

So you can put your images to `Resources.resx` file, and add them in appropriate place in code. For example in constructor of you `UserControl`/`Form`, after call to `InitializeComponent()` by code like this:

```
  _imageList.Images.Add(Resources.Image32);
  _imageList.Images.SetKeyName(0, "Image32");
  _myButton.Image = 0;
```

*(This info is available in comments to response marked answer, I've added this as answer so it would be harder to miss another available option)*

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great, I didn't understand why the transparency didn't look good. But, I think, the last line should be `_myButton.ImageIndex = 0;`