# Weird White Outline Around C# Images

Tags: c#, image, border, imagelist

I am using an ImageList in C# to display images on buttons dynamically. When I set the image index, it displays the image like so:

[image: Image in C# Program]

Here is the same image in Photoshop:

[image: Image in Photoshop]

Comment: May want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10372797/1218281 Looks like an issue with transparency not being fully supported.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem using image with transparent background. Setting appropriate color depth solved the issue.

```
imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who has this problem,

Open all the images in an image editor and replace transparency with something like (255, 0, 255) and in Visual Studio set "Transparency Color" to (255, 0, 255).