# Image losing quality when displayed via imagelist

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox, imagelist

I would like to use `ImageList` to display images in a loop using a timer. It works fine, except that the same image that is displayed vividly on a `PictureBox` loses its quality when the same `PictureBox` is supposed to display the picture from an image list.

Image when shown directly in `PictureBox`:

[image]

Image when shown in `PictureBox` but via the `ImageList` (`pictureBox1.Image = imglist.Images[0];`):

[image]

My picture is a `128x128` png and here is the designer code for both my `PictureBox` and `ImageList`:

```
// 
// pictureBox1
// 
this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 78);
this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 128);
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1;
this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;

// 
// imglist
// 
this.imglist.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imglist.ImageStream")));
this.imglist.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.imglist.Images.SetKeyName(0, "1423093311_supportfemale-48.png");
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;` ?

Comment: @Hughnited yes but I get the same result.

Comment: Looking at the pictures, it doesn't seem like it's loosing quality, but rather that the imageList is adding a border...

Comment: @DominikB true. But why it appears?

Comment: Hers a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372797/imagelist-32-bit-images-lose-quality

Comment: You are seeing the effect of semitranparent pixels. Try to avoid them if you can!

Comment: Check to make sure `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` is called at the start of the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying images using ImageList for PictureBox will degrade image quality sometimes.

Try this alternative:

1. Right click on Project > Select Properties > Select Resources from left tab > select images from horizontal menues > click on Add Resource(add required image from your machine) > save
   ...this will add image to resource with **imagename**.extension
2. In fromNameLoad(any load method which is executed first), write:
   Image **imagename1** = Properties.Resources.**imagename**;
3. Use it with PictureBox:
   PictureboxVar.BackgroundImage = **imagename1**;